# How Can I Set Value To output parameter in sql stored procedure within select statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Stored Procedure in sql server 2008 used to paginating data returned from product table in database. what i want is return total pages count in the same select statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetProducts]
    @PageSize int = 10, 
    @PageNumber int = 1,
    @ProductCode nvarchar(50) = null,
    @ProductName nvarchar(100) = null,
    @TotalPages int = null output 
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    SELECT TOP (@PageSize) *, @TotalPages = COUNT(*)  FROM (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId ASC) offset, * FROM (
         SELECT *, count(*) over() AS TotalRows
         FROM Products
        ) myquery
        ) paginator
        WHERE offset >= (((@PageSize * @PageNumber) - @PageSize)) +1 and offset <= (@PageSize * @PageNumber)
```

Comment: Are you trying to do `count(*) * pagesize` to get total count?  Your code is a bit confusing.

Comment: Not sure I understand your code, but you can just execute multiple selects to return multiple output parameters.

Comment: with out  @TotalPages = COUNT(*) code work but i need return Count(*) in output parameter in the same select statement

Comment: if i execute multiple selects to return multiple output parameters what about performance for procedure

Comment: Store your resultset in a temp table.  Get both of your output parms from that table, instead of running the full query, and then select count(*) from the full query.

Answer (score -1):

you cannot retrieve values from a Select statement and assign value to a variable at the same time. In your particular case since you are only assigning the number or rows returned from your select statement you can use a slightly different approach to get what you want.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GetProducts]
    @PageSize int = 10, 
    @PageNumber int = 1,
    @ProductCode nvarchar(50) = null,
    @ProductName nvarchar(100) = null,
    @TotalPages int = null output 
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP (@PageSize) * 
     FROM (
           SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ProductId ASC) offset, * 
              FROM (
                    SELECT *, count(*) over() AS TotalRows
                    FROM Products
           ) myquery
        ) paginator
        WHERE offset >= (((@PageSize * @PageNumber) - @PageSize)) +1 
         AND offset <= (@PageSize * @PageNumber)

    -- here assign value to your output parameter using the following

     SELECT @TotalPages = @@ROWCOUNT;
END
```

*Note*

Avoid using `SELECT *` instead use Column names, only the columns you actually want to retrieve.